# How can I make a dropdown text update after it's been selected and the user scrolls down the page using vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript

I have a dropdown menu that updates the text within the dropdown as the user scrolls through the page. The problem I have is if I select an item from the dropdown and then scroll through the page the text shown in the dropdown is not updated with the current section of the page. It works when you are scrolling through the page, so long as you don't select an item from the dropdown menu.

I want the text to update when scrolling even after the dropdown has been selected.

Here is the code in question:

```
const register = document.getElementById("register");
const pairing = document.getElementById("pairing");
const deviceUnlock = document.getElementById("device-unlock");
let count = 0;

function smoothScroll(stopElement) {
    scrollToElement(stopElement, {
        duration: 750,
    });
}

const setupInstructions = [
    register,
    pairing,
    deviceUnlock,
];

function updateNamedAnchor(urlParameters) {
    history.replaceState(null, "", `#${urlParameters}`);
}

function updateUrlOnScroll() {
    window.onscroll = function() {
        const currentDropdownElement = document.getElementById('dropdown-current')
        // replace # in url with register section
        let scrolly = window.scrollY + 114;

        if (scrolly < register.offsetTop) {
            currentDropdownElement.textContent = 'Select Section'
            updateNamedAnchor('')
            count = 0;
        } else if (scrolly >= register.offsetTop && scrolly < pairing.offsetTop) {
            currentDropdownElement.textContent = 'Register'
            updateNamedAnchor('register')
            count = setupInstructions.indexOf(register);
        } else if (scrolly >= pairing.offsetTop && scrolly < deviceUnlock.offsetTop) {
            currentDropdownElement.textContent = 'Pairing'
            updateNamedAnchor('pairing')
            count = setupInstructions.indexOf(pairing);
        } else if (scrolly >= deviceUnlock.offsetTop) {
            currentDropdownElement.textContent = 'Device Unlock'
            updateNamedAnchor('device-unlock')
            count = setupInstructions.indexOf(deviceUnlock);
        }
    };
}
```

I will note that it works as intended **ONLY IF** I select the "Select Section" item in the dropdown.

Here is the code that handles that particular dropdown item:

```
function onDropdownClicked() {
    const currentOption = document.getElementById('dropdown-current');
    currentOption.textContent = 'Select Section';
}

function dropdownClicked() {
    const dropdown = document.getElementById('nav-dropdown')
    dropdown.addEventListener('click', onDropdownClicked)
}
```

I feel like, I'm even more confused by the fact that it works when i select the option that i added an event listener to, but the other ones won't work as intended when they are selected.

UPDATE:

HTML to go with this:

```html
 <div style="position:fixed; z-index: 50; height: 100px; width: 100%; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: space-between; background-color: gray; height: 8%;">
    <div id="prev">
        <p class="button-prev">&lt;</p>
    </div>
    <div id='section-dropdown' style="background-color: gray; height: 40%;">
        <select id="nav-dropdown" class="text-input dropdown dropdown-arrow" onchange="window.location.href=this.value">
            <option id="dropdown-current" class="dropdown-item" value="#">Select Section</option>
            <option id="dropdown-register" class="dropdown-item" value="#register">Register</option>
            <option id="dropdown-pairing" class="dropdown-item" value="#pairing">Pairing</option>
            <option id="dropdown-device-unlock" class="dropdown-item" value="#device-unlock">Device Unlock</option>
       </select>
    </div>
    <div id="next">
        <p class="button-next">&gt;</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I feel like we need some html to go with this. Can't tell if the ids are all correct...

Comment: Also assuming there's no error in the dev console. But coincidentally, it sounds like the one that works calls updateNamedAnchor with no param and the others have a param. Maybe look there?

Comment: @Nikki9696 I added the HTML, also I wouldn't think that updateNamedAnchor would be related to the dropdown since it just updated the anchor tag in the url with the corresponding section tag

Comment: dropdown-current is an option - is your intention actually to select an option in nav-dropdown? or are you trying to update the text of that option?

Comment: also, window.location.href set will [cause a navigation event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/href)

Comment: dropdown-current exists so that when you scroll through the page it will update the text of that specific option to reflect the current section of the page. 

I have an onClick event that will reset that text if the dropdown is clicked so it appears as though the dropdown is "scrolling" through the options as you scroll through the page

Comment: I'm a little confused. You have an onchange event for the dropdown. So, if the user selects one, it basically reloads the page and wipes out that changed text. Unless you have more code not posted here intercepting that, but if that's the case, I'm not sure why it's there?

Comment: No the onchange event im referring to for the dropdown is only triggered when the dropdown is pressed, all it does it change the textcontent of the dropdown. Because as you scroll depending on where you're at on the page the textcontent of "select section" option is changed, and when you click the dropdown itself it changes the text back to it's default state removing the text that was added during the onscroll event